# SSIS Ensure a sequence container is not marked as failed if a specific task fails

Tags: ssis-2016

Consider the following scenario for an SSIS package:

A Sequence Container contains two jobs for loading data from an Excel file:

- Job A: Attempts to load data from an Excel file following a specific file definition.
- Job B: In case JOB A fails, Job B will be executed instead.

Outside the container, a final task is executed to reset data.

[image: Job A is executed successfully: Container is marked as completed successfully.]

The issue I have, however, is that if JOB A fails, even though JOB B takes over and manages to process the file correctly, the container is marked as a failure.

[image: Job A fails: JOB B is executed successfully, but container is marked as failed.]

Although I can circumvent this issue with the use of some variables and "Precedent Constraint" (this can be seen in the second screenshot above), I wonder if there is a more elegant way, in which I simply ensure that the Sequence Container is not marked as failed is the first task of loading data fails.

Now, the first thing that comes to mind for me is the use of `MaximumErrorCount` property on the container. However I have other tasks within the container and if they fail it could mess with the logic.

Perhaps nesting yet another container for just JOBS A and B within the existing container would be the way forward?

But really (I'm a hopeless idealist) what I was hoping to find is some sort of property for JOB A that says *if job A fails, don't mark the container as a failure* in the simplest way possible. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the **Propagate** variable for the OnError Event Handler of the task within the sequence?

Check [this link](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/08/05/continue-package-execution-after-error-in-ssis/) for info. Basically, you disable propagation of the OnError event so the ancestor tasks (or sequence in this case) don't receive the error.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had a look into the article and I basically tried to create an OnError event handler for the JOB_A task. Then I changed the Propagate variable to False, but the scope of it is wider than just JOB_A. So based on my limited knowledge it seems like this would change the entire package.

Comment: Actually it works like a charm. It is just the SSDT interface in Visual Studio which is not that intuitive when looking at the variables in this case.

Comment: Another good link explaining how to handle this issue: https://bit.ly/2UheZWZ